# QPushButton usage

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qtcore, qt-signals

In my application i have two buttons and one function and when i click certain  button function takes certain parameter and  executing with its value, when i click another button it function takes another parameter and executing, how to do that? All of this things is done dynamically. Function and buttons are in different classes.

```
connect(AddButtonSimpleWindow,SIGNAL(clicked(MyWindowSettings)),area,SLOT(AddSubWindow(MyWindowSettings)));
connect(AddButtonParameterWindow,SIGNAL(clicked(MyWindowSettings)),area,SLOT(AddSubWindow(MyWindowSettings)));
```

Where i should emit signal? And how to override it?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Isn't your code already doing what you want? It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Sory, but i just fogot adout * when connect button with the slot)

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Can you show more code?

Comment: it does not matter. It works) Thanks)

Comment: Could you please add some more code to your original question as it was before the fix? It would help the readers. Failing that, I will do that myself with some dummy code, but it would be better if you could it yourself. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where i should emit signal? And how to override it?

This part of your code looks correct if the sender and receiver objects are pointers. Please make sure they are.